# Phoneauthprovider verifyphonenumber timeout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I am working with Firebase Phone Authentication method.

```
 val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()

PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
```

The code work fine with a good internet connection, but when I connect to wifi without internet or with a slow connection the `onVerificationFailed` methode is called after 60 sec. I can solved this with a `Asynctask` or `Handler`. Is there are any way to set time out to verifyPhoneNumber or trigger the `onVerificationFailed` methode.

Comment: There's a `.setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` in the code you shared. Did you try increasing that?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. yes I tried to increase and decrease the amount but the timeout is always 60sec.